# C++ short enum problems with InterlockedCompareExchange16 (with VS2012)

Tags: c++11, enums, volatile, interlocked, static-assert

Having referenced this question: [Can an enum class be converted to the underlying type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589417/can-an-enum-class-be-converted-to-the-underlying-type).

In my code I have effectively:

```
enum class STATE : short
{
    EMPTY,
    PRESENT,
    PARTIAL,
};

volatile STATE state;
```

Then I write a `typedef` and a `static_assert`:

```
typedef volatile std::underlying_type<STATE> state_type;
static_assert (sizeof (state_type) == sizeof (short), "Error - unsafe for use with InterlockedCompareExchange16");
```

Finally I attempt to set the state with `InterlockedCompareExchange16`:

```
if (InterlockedCompareExchange16 (static_cast<state_type *>(&state), STATE::PRESENT, STATE::EMPTY) == STATE::EMPTY)
{
}
```

I am getting the following errors from VS2012:

1. My `static_assert` fails complaining that `state_type` is not the same size as `short`
2. The `static_cast` complains that it cannot cast from `volatile STATE *` to `state_type *`

Please can anyone give me any pointers for how to best fix my code?

Comment: Please do not modify the question in response to answers. It is confusing for people coming to the question later and makes the answers redundant. Rolled back.

Comment: Just to admit my failing, previous errors mentioned were down to me incorrectly using 'underlying_type', but I still get the 'static_cast' complaining.

Comment: Sorry @hmjd.  I've just added an explanatory comment - is that sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

From [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type):

> Defines a member typedef type of type that is the underlying type for the enumeration T.

Change to:

```
typedef typename std::underlying_type<STATE>::type state_type;
                                            //^^^^
```

A motivation for the strongly typed `enum class` was to prevent conversion to `int`, so attempting to cast to the underlying type conflicts with the intended use of the `enum`s (see [Strongly Typed Enums (revision 3)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf)).

Instead of using OS specific threading mechanisms use [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) template that was added to c++11:

```
std::atomic<STATE> state(STATE::EMPTY);
STATE expected(STATE::EMPTY);
if (state.compare_exchange_strong(expected, STATE::PRESENT))
{
    // 'state' set to 'PRESENT'.
}
```

This removes the requirement for `static_assert` and does not require any casting.

Comment: Thank you - yes, I just spotted that error myself.  This fixes one error - I still get the 'static_cast' complaining.  I will update the question.

Comment: Unfortunately the Microsoft compiler gives the error: C2664: '_InterlockedCompareExchange16' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'volatile STATE *' to 'volatile SHORT *' if I don't perform any cast.

Comment: I think that my core problem was that incorrect usage of std::underlying_type though. Should I close the question since it's unlikely to benefit other people.