# c++11 vs c++ - enums differences

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, strongly-typed-enum

```
//c++03
enum Something
{
    S1 = 0,
    S2,
    SCOUNT
};
int arr[SCOUNT];

//c++11
enum class Something
{
    S1 = 0,
    S2,
    SCOUNT
};
int arr[(int) Something::SCOUNT];
```

How can I use enums in this case without casting count of enum to int?

Comment: The first version continues to work in C++11, but I suppose you want to reap the benefits for the actual enum members and only want a way to get the number of enum members?

Comment: Isn't the benefit of `enum class` that you can't mix the values of different enums?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I use enums in this case without casting count of enum to int?*

You can't... But you can remove the `class` from `enum class`

The `class` keyword means that you can't implicitly convert between that `enum` and `int` Removing the `class` keyword means your `enum` will work in the same way as in previous versions of C++. You won't need the cast, but you loose the safety of `strongly typed enums` by allowing implicit casts to integral values.

```
//C++11
enum class Something
{
    S1 = 0,
    S2,
    SCOUNT
};
int arr[SCOUNT]; // ERRROR

//C++11
enum Something
{
    S1 = 0,
    S2,
    SCOUNT
};
int arr[SCOUNT]; // OK
```

You can read more about `strongly typed enums` [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c19083/C-2011-Stronglytyped-Enums.htm)

---

The other option is to cast it, like you are doing. But you should avoid the old `C-style cast` and use `static_cast<>` instead as this has better type safety and is more explicit.

```
//C++11
enum class Something
{
    S1 = 0,
    S2,
    SCOUNT
};
int arr[static_cast< size_t > ( SCOUNT ) ]; // OK
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually in the second case, you cannot write that without  casting.

Since you have to use cast, what you can do now is to use **better** cast instead of c-style cast:

```
int arr[to_integral(Something::SCOUNT)];
```

where `to_integral` is defined as:

```
#include <type_traits> //it is where std::underlying_type is defined

template<typename E>
constexpr auto to_integral(E e) -> typename std::underlying_type<E>::type 
{
   return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(e);
}
```

Now this function template is reusable. You can use for any C++11-style *enum* type. It also deduces the underlying type, so you don't have to mention in your code anymore. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589417/can-an-enum-class-be-converted-to-the-underlying-type) for detailed explanation.