# How do I statically assert the value of enum elements?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
enum class MyEnum { A, B };
static_assert(A == 0 && B == 1); // error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You're also missing the string literal part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole purpose of adding `enum class` to the language was to make enumeration *strongly typed* and *scoped*. This means:

- You cannot use just `A` without qualification.You have to use `MyEnum::A`.
- You cannot treat it like `int`  —  strongly-typed enum cannot be compared with integral type without *explicit* cast.

So you have to do something like this:

```
static_assert(to_integral(MyEnum::A)== 0 && to_integral(MyEnum::B)==1, 
                              "your message");
```

And take the implementation of `to_integral` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589417/can-an-enum-class-be-converted-to-the-underlying-type) : it is a generic implementation, so you don't have to assume or figure out what the underlying type of `MyEnum` is.

Alternatively, you can define `operator==` for `MyEnum`. Make sure it is `constexpr`:

```
constexpr bool operator==(MyEnum x, int y) { return to_integral(x) == y; }
constexpr bool operator==(int x, MyEnum y) { return y == x; }
```

Now you can write this:

```
static_assert(MyEnum::A== 0 && MyEnum::B ==1, "your message");
```

Just for the sake of completeness, I copy-paste the implementation of `to_integral` from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589417/can-an-enum-class-be-converted-to-the-underlying-type):

```
#include <type_traits> //must include it

template<typename E>
constexpr auto to_integral(E e) -> typename std::underlying_type<E>::type 
{
   return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(e);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code have two problems:

1. `static_assert` takes two arguments
2. You can't compare `A` and `0`, because:

   1. `MyEnum` is not just `enum`, but `class enum`. So, firstly, you have to write `MyEnum::A`
   2. You can't compare `MyEnum::A` with `0`, because `MyEnum` is a strongly-typed enum. You have to cast it to `int` before comparing.

But if you are using strongly typed enumerations, I guess, you don't need to compare it with `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

Try to access through the enum, and cast the enum values:

```
enum class MyEnum { A, B };
static_assert((int)MyEnum::A == 0 && (int)MyEnum::B == 1, "message");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have four problems. You need

```
enum class MyEnum { A, B };
static_assert(MyEnum::A == MyEnum(0) && MyEnum::B == MyEnum(1), "invalid values");
```

which fixes

- the scope of the enum values (`A` vs. `MyEnum::A`)
- converts the integer values to enums correctly so the comparison is valid
- adds the missing error message for `static_assert`

What's the fourth problem?

**You need to compile in C++11 mode** (this is what the others are missing!). Add `-std=c++11` to the compiler's command line. How do I know? Because of the error message you got, this only happens when compiling in C++03 mode.

Answer (score 1):

static_assert takes two arguments, the second being a string to output if the assertion fails.

Should be something like,

```
static_assert(A == 0 && B == 1, "Enum values are not as expected");
```