# Using `reinterpret_cast` on an enum class - valid or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, reinterpret-cast, enum-class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> using Underlying = std::underlying_type_t<T>;

enum class ETest : int
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
};

template<typename T> auto& castEnum(T& mX) noexcept
{
    // `static_cast` does not compile
    // return static_cast<Underlying<T>&>(mX);

    return reinterpret_cast<Underlying<T>&>(mX);
}

int main()
{
    auto x(ETest::Zero);
    castEnum(x) = 1;
    assert(x == ETest::One);

    return 0;
}
```

[**ideone**](http://ideone.com/IjzyAQ)

Is this code guaranteed to always work? Or is it undefined behavior?

Comment: This appears to violate the strict aliasing rule, unless `int` counts as a base class of `enum class ETest` or something

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19477123/2073257), see if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard is a bit unclear:

> **3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]**
>
> 10 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> [...]
>
> (10.4) -- a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>
> [...]

This could be legitimately read as saying that the signed or unsigned type corresponding to an enumeration type is its underlying type, but I'd think this is meant to cover *only* accessing integer types through their other-signed corresponding type, that the underlying type of an enumeration type does not count as the (un)signed type corresponding to that enumeration type.

At least GCC agrees with this: it gives an aliasing warning for

```
enum E : int { };
int f(E e) { return *(int *) &e; }
```

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

strongly hinting that it will optimise on the assumption that no such aliasing takes place in your program.

Comment: So, according to the warning gcc gives us, can we conclude that `enumCast` is actually unsafe and shouldn't be used? It's a shame, it's pretty convenient for defining serialization helper functions :P

Comment: @VittorioRomeo For serialization, you should consider `memcpy` et al. It works for *all* trivially copyable types, including enumeration types.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo It's hypothetically possible that GCC's optimiser and GCC's warning logic are out of sync, that the optimiser will take such aliasing into account, but I wouldn't rely on that without a very strong proof. :)

Comment: The bullet " a  type  similar  (as  deﬁned  in  4.4)  to  the  dynamic  type  of  the  object" looks like potential permission, but the definition of similar types doesn't appear to include enums vis-a-vis underlying type.

Comment: @BenVoigt I saw that too, but you're right that that doesn't apply: that only applies to pointer types.