How can I use enums as arguments to functions that take non-enum references as arguments?
I have one library for interface with I2C devices (read/write) and a another that acts as a driver for a specific I2C device. I'm trying to do two somewhat independent things here:

Format my I2C read/write functions to act on reference inputs and return a bool to to be used for error handling.
Use enums in my driver code to avoid magic numbers.

In general, it feels like there should be a better way to do this so I'm looking for any suggestions on how to do this without reinterpret_cast while still meeting the goals. I don't want to add an overload for the enum and I'm hoping to avoid making temporary variables.
When I try to read a device register into a variable declared as one of the enum types, I get several flavors of errors about the inability to convert between enums and other types. I've think been able to make it work with reinterpret_cast but I've gotten the impression that this should be avoided when possible.

I condensed my real program into a representative example which is shown below.
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

// i2cCommunication.h GENERIC I2C COMMUNICATION FILE

// This function is part of a generic library that cannot see the enum definition
bool read(uint8_t& input_ref)
{
    if(!true) // This would be where you write the device address to the I2C bus and see if it was acknowledged
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    input_ref = 0b01; // This would be where you actually read from the device
    return true; // This bool would be set by a separate function that reports read status
}
    

// driver.h DEVICE DRIVER FILE

// #include "i2cCommunication.h"
// This enum is defined in a header for a device "driver"
enum GainLevel
{
    GAIN1   = 0b00,
    GAIN2   = 0b01
};

GainLevel gain = GAIN1;

bool updateGainLevel()
{
    if(read(static_cast<uint8_t&>(gain)))
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(gain); // Only here for the example
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


// MAIN FILE
// #include "driver.h"
int main() 
{
    updateGainLevel();
    return 0;
}

Error as shown:
error: invalid 'static_cast' from type 'GainLevel' to type 'uint8_t&' {aka 'unsigned char&'}


Probably easier to just use constants rather than enums

Alan has has it. #define CONSTANTS  0, etc.. saves space and makes the ADS1115 code much easier to read.

C++11: underlying_type, C++14: underlying_type_t, C++23: to_underlying.

The problem is that gain is an enum type, and cannot be casted like that into a uint8_t&. The enum type might not even be 8 bits, and therefore using reinterpret_cast for a reference/pointer is not a good idea (it rarely is).
The issue is not related to enums in particular. You would have the same issue without enums, if you tried e.g. to cast a uint32_t into a reference to uint8_t (uint8_t&). This is because the function using the casted reference (or pointer for that matter) will not access the underlying object properly.
To solve it, you can call read with a local variable of type uint8_t, and then use static_cast to assign it to gain:
bool updateGainLevel()
{
    uint8_t g;
    if (read(g))
    {
        gain = static_cast<GainLevel>(g);
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(gain); // Only here for the example
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


I feel like it wouldn't matter if its 8 bits because you can cast uint32_t into uint8_t no problem. My impression is that its not the size that causes the issue but something more specific about the nature of enums. Regardless, I was trying to avoid temporary variables.

You cast a value of 32 bits into 8 bits (assuming it is small enough), but casting a reference which is like a pointer is more problematic. The reference/pointer in read will assume the target is 8 bit, whereas in practice it could be otherwise (and the target value could be e.g. stored also using the last 3 bytes). Using a temporary is the safer solution.

@Brendan Casting a uint32_t to a uint8_t creates a new uint32_t based on the original value. It does not treat the uint8_t as if it were a uint32_t, which is what a reference must do.

@wohlstad just a quick thought: would a reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&> be safe when the enum is defined as enum GainLevel: uint8_t {...}?

@grek40 It might, but I'm not in favor of using reinterpret_cast in general (and especially when there are easy alternatives like using a temp).

@grek40 That reinterpret_cast is not safe for most enums (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19477123/5754656), but if uint8_t is unsigned char it's fine

You can make something like std::out_ptr but for enum types:
template<typename Enum>
struct out_enum {
private:
    Enum& e;
    std::underlying_type_t<Enum> out{};
public:
    constexpr explicit out_enum(Enum& e) noexcept : e(e) {}
    out_enum(out_enum&&) = delete;
    out_enum& operator=(out_enum&&) = delete;
    constexpr operator std::underlying_type_t<Enum>&() noexcept { return out; }
    constexpr ~out_enum() { e = static_cast<Enum>(out); }
};


bool updateGainLevel()
{
    if(read(out_enum(gain)))
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(gain); // Only here for the example
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Or if the underlying type ends up being different than what you want:
template<typename Enum, typename Underlying = std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>
struct out_enum_t {
private:
    Enum& e;
    Underlying out{};
public:
    constexpr explicit out_enum_t(Enum& e) noexcept : e(e) {}
    out_enum_t(out_enum_t&&) = delete;
    out_enum_t& operator=(out_enum_t&&) = delete;
    constexpr operator Underlying&() noexcept { return out; }
    constexpr ~out_enum_t() { e = static_cast<Enum>(out); }
};

template<typename Underlying, typename Enum>
constexpr out_enum_t<Enum, Underlying> out_enum(Enum& e) {
    return out_enum_t<Enum, Underlying>(e);
}

template<typename Enum>
constexpr out_enum_t<Enum> out_enum(Enum& e) {
    return out_enum_t<Enum>(e);
}


bool updateGainLevel()
{
    if(read(out_enum<uint8_t>(gain)))
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(gain); // Only here for the example
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

