# Passing enum to overload function

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to pass an enum which is basically a byte to a overload resolution, but it doesn't work.

Here is the enum:

```
enum class WriteOp : uint8_t {
  kAdd = 0,
  kDelete
};
```

Here are the overloads:

```
 void copy_out(uint8_t& v) { getn((char*) &v, 1); }
 void copy_out(uint16_t& v) { getn((char*) &v, 2); }
 void copy_out(uint32_t& v) { getn((char*) &v, 4); }
 void copy_out(uint64_t& v) { getn((char*) &v, 8); }
```

And here is a typical error messages I'm getting:

```
main.cpp:164:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'WriteOp' to 'uint8_t &' (aka 'unsigned char &') for 1st argument
void copy_out(uint8_t& v) { getn((char*) &v, 1); }
```

Any simple and elegant way to do that?

Comment: make an WriteOp overload?

Comment: You have a *strongly typed enum*, the point of this is to make it a different type (ie not implicitly casted). You should either cast it or make an overload.

Comment: One specific feature of `enum class` is that it is not implicitly convertible. If you want that, use an ordinary `enum`.

Comment: @Frank You have explicitly to convert a scoped enumerator to a desired type.

Comment: See also [converting-enum-to-underlying-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589417/can-an-enum-class-be-converted-to-the-underlying-type).

Comment: _"I'm trying to pass an enum"_ No you're not. _"which is basically a byte"_ No it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class E,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>{}>* = nullptr
>
void copy_out(E& e){
  getn(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e),sizeof(e));
}
```

if you are taking an enum, take an enum.

The above takes any enum, and does a `getn`.

With a bit of refactoring, you could move all calls to `getn` and its unsafe casts into one function.

Answer (score 2):

You have a *strongly typed enum* the whole point of these are they are not implicitly convertible and can have scope. You can do 1 of 3 things:

1. Create an overload for your type: `void copy_out(WriteOp& v) { getn((char*) &v, 1); }`
2. Explicitly cast your enum `copy_out(&(uint8_t)my_enum);`
3. Use a standard enum.

---

```
enum WriteOp {
  kAdd = 0,
  kDelete
};
```

Comment: Note that many compilers support sized non-class enums.  Oh, and are you certain that an eum can be implicitly cast to a reference to its underlying type?  Or that its underlying type is one of those types?